# Changing Facebook Oauth redirect url

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth

In our Java EE app we are invoking the fb oauth flow to get accessToken. 
For this purpose we make a call with the callback url to the fb server with app key and secret.

At this moment the same url is provided in the fb app url section.

However, is it possible if we can some how change the redirect url to go to a different server ?  I have seen just changing the callback url in the code does not work.  Looks like it has to be same in the code as well as in the fb application.

This make very difficult to test or use the same app to try things from two different web servers.

Any advise on this?

Comment: Great question. I'm going to try passing query params so the authority and path are equal and FB is happy, but it gives me some params back so I can switch. Alternatively, I need to append something to the STATE param.

Comment: this wont work if servers are entirely different. or may be you need to make sure both the servers run at the same time etc. not a very practical solution though technically possible

Comment: Just to come back on the above, I seem to be able to add one query parameter and Facebook includes it on callback/redirect. Two params doesn't seem to work, however. I know this isn't what Vik wanted but it might help others landing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible. Just redirect user to your redirect_uri which will redirect you to the correct location

> The URL to redirect to after the user clicks a button in the dialog.
>   The URL you specify must be a URL of with the same Base Domain as
>   specified in your app's settings, a Canvas URL of the form
>   https://apps.facebook.com/YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE or a Page Tab URL of the
>   form https://www.facebook.com/PAGE_USERNAME/app_YOUR_APP_ID

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/

Comment: are you sure? any doc references ? its a big issue in that case

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons you can't change the redirect url. Facebook check that you provide the same redirect url as you gave when you registered the application. The way I solved this was to register one application on facebook for each server.

Comment: The problem I have with this is that the Facebook authentication page will open in a new window. How do you make it happen in the same window?

Answer (score -1):

[Here is Solution from Promo Group](http://promo.org.il/en/blog/OAuth-multilang-multidomain)

One of the options - to add a 2nd domain (address mirror the primary site) in 

 `Settings » Basic tab at the top» Mobile Site URL`